# "-2146893807 NTE_NOT_FOUND" when repair certificate store

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate

I try to repair my certificate store in Windows 10 by doing

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>certutil -store -user my ‎330000019dba8d5dddb98062a900000000019d
my "Personal"
CertUtil: -store command FAILED: 0x80090011 (-2146893807 NTE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: Object was not found.
```

I have double check from the MMC, certificate details the serial number of my certificate.  But I still fail to repair the certificate store.

Comment: this may help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759048%28v=ws.10%29.aspx Also note, search for the error numbers (0x80090011) rather than the return code. -2146893807 is the lowest number you can express with a 32bit signed integer, so it just means "No Value Here".

Comment: I tried that. But it does not  help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when trying to export a PFX. It turns out I just had to export to `C:\cert.pfx` instead of just `cert.pfx` (it was trying to export the file to the cert store ( `Cert:\LocalMachine\My` ).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.  I did the following to fix the problem.

-Used certificate serial number instead of thumbprint.  I am not sure why thumbprint wouldn't work it was working in the past.
-when i was pasting the serial number it was bring in a extra odd character in the beginning. I removed that character.